# C# Get Keys from a Dictionary<string, Stream>

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

Suppose I have a Dictionary like so:

```
Dictionary<string, Stream>
```

How can I get a list (or IEnumerable or whatever) of **JUST** the Keys from this dictionary? Is this possible?

I *could* enumerate the dictionary, and extract the keys one by one, but I was hoping to avoid this.

In my instance, the Dictionary contains a list of filenames (file1.doc, filex.bmp etc...) and the stream content of the file from another part of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KeyCollection Dictionary(TKey, TValue).Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx)

Comment: I initially tried this however it didn't provider me with what i want - is this acceptable? var x = (IEnumerable<string>)attachments.Keys; - casting it as a IEnumerable of string??

Comment: KeyCollection already implements IEnumerable<string>: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6.aspx , no casting needing.

Comment: @alex `KeyCollection` is already an `IEnumerable<string>` - there's no need for the cast.

Answer (score 1):

[`Dictionary(TKey, TValue).Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx)

Typically you can discover these things through code-completion/IntelliSense.

Similarly, there is a [Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx) property:

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary<T,T>.Keys` returns a [KeyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6.aspx).  This has the IEnumerable interface.

so...

```
foreach(string key in Dictionary<string,Stream>.Keys)
{


}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public IEnumerable<long> ReturnSomeKeys()
{
    var foo = new Dictionary<long, string>();
    return foo.Keys;
}
```

This does what you want.